# GIS roads data with maximum speed limit

Tags: road

I'm looking for street/roads data in California with maximum speed limit attributed. TIGER data doesn't have the speed limit data, and open street map data is only attributed at about 25%. I'm looking for either open source or proprietary data. Is there any available?

Comment: What about TeleNav data?

Comment: If it may be open data then the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[TeleAtlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tele_Atlas) used to have speed limits. It's proprietary though. Not sure if the data is still available after it's acquired by other companies.

Answer (score 0):

Speed limit data is available with the Google Maps API with premium plan using the roads API